# SQL Performance Query that checks for values in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I'm using MySQL

I have three tables:

```
accounts {
    account_id,
    username
}

account_ips {
    idaccount_ips,
    account_id,
    ip
}

account_bans {
    ban_id
    account_id,
    expires
}
```

Need to get grouped count of accounts per ip that are not in bans table. (See query below)

I've tried the following, but it is way too slow (44s):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.account_id, count(DISTINCT a.account_id)
  FROM account_ips AS a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
      FROM account_bans AS b
     WHERE b.expires > 1340341272 AND b.account_id = a.account_id)
 GROUP BY a.ip
HAVING count(DISTINCT a.account_id) > 3
 ORDER BY count(DISTINCT a.account_id) DESC;
```

Explain output the following:

```
1, 'PRIMARY', 'a', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 304745, 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'b', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 1851, 'Using where'
```

Comment: Answerers may find this fiddle useful : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61a95/1 Compare the execution plan of OP's query vs. your own (full discretion - sqlfiddle.com is my site)

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize there was an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables? Can you post `EXPLAIN` output for your query, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do it this way -

```
SELECT AIP.IP, COUNT(AIP.ACCOUNT_ID)
FROM ACCOUNT_IPS AIP
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A ON AIP.ACCOUNT_ID=A.ACCOUNT_ID
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT_BANS AB ON A.ACCOUNT_ID=AB.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE
AB.BAN_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY AIP.IP
```

If you also need to consider b.expires > 1340341272 then the query would be -

```
SELECT AIP.IP, COUNT(AIP.ACCOUNT_ID)
FROM ACCOUNT_IPS AIP
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A ON AIP.ACCOUNT_ID=A.ACCOUNT_ID
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT_BANS AB ON A.ACCOUNT_ID=AB.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE
AB.BAN_ID IS NULL
OR AB.EXPIRES <= 1340341272
GROUP BY AIP.IP
```

Comment: This query takes almost 8x as long to run as my other query.

Comment: `JOINS are always way faster than sub query` So maybe because your sub query is already cached you fill its faster. Subsequent runs should be faster in that case.

Comment: Let me add some information that might help optimize this query. There are 400k records in account_ips (and will grow quickly), and only 2000 records in account_bans. I need to this query to execute in under 5s. =[ is that an unrealistic expectation? Should I do something with indexes to speed up the lookups?

Comment: you need to index ACCOUNT_ID in all. that will help.

Comment: Nevermind, I had setup my indexes wrong the first time. Your solution works. Thanks so much for the advice!

Comment: I ended up with this following query: `SELECT DISTINCT AIP.account_id, AIP.ip, COUNT(DISTINCT AIP.account_id)
FROM account_ips AIP
LEFT JOIN accounts A ON AIP.account_id=A.account_id
LEFT JOIN account_bans AB ON A.account_id=AB.account_id
WHERE
AB.ban_id IS NULL
OR AB.expires <= 1340341272
GROUP BY AIP.ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AIP.account_id) > 3
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT AIP.account_id) DESC` which takes 1.2s now after setting up the indices. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `left join` and get the nulls for the ips in the right table, as opposed to `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
FROM account_ips a
LEFT JOIN account_bans b ON b.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE b.account_id IS NULL
```